# Javascript max and min not working

Tags: javascript, input, max, min

I am trying to create a page that lets the user enter three numbers, and have the max and min values printed below from the input.  I've used both the Math.max/min functions and also tried an if statement but When I click submit nothing shows up.  Some insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
function max() {
    var x = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("num3").value;

    var maximum = Math.max(parseInt(x), parseInt(y), parseInt(z));

    document.getElementById("max").innerHTML= maximum;
    }
    function min() {

    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("num3").value);


    document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = Math.min(x,y,z);
    }
```

And here is my html

```
<p>Enter First Number:</p>
<input type="text" name = "number1" id="num1"><br>
<p>Enter Second Number</p>
<input type="text" name = "number2" id="num2"><br>
<p>Enter third number</p>
<input type="text" name = "number3" id="num3"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="max(); min(); "><br /> 
<p>Max =</p><p id ="max"></p><br />
<p>Min =</p><p id ="min"></p><br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `<input type="submit"/>` to `<button type="submit" value="" onclick="minmax();">Submit</button>`

and add JS function:

```
function minmax() {
    min();
    max();
}
```

Comment: They type of element is irrelevant. How the functions are called isn't. This answer doesn't explain why the OP doesn't work, or why this answer does.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems related to how you are attaching your event.

It works OK when I use:

```
document.querySelector( '[type="submit"]' ).addEventListener( 'click', function() {
   max();
   min();
}, false );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yemxrmqq/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the tag related to the button, instead of:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="max(); min(); "><br />
```

just put:

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="max(); min()">Click</button><br />
```

Comment: How does that fix the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here tell you why your code didn't work.

Identifiers in inline listeners are first resolved as properties of the element on which they are placed. [Input elements](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-input-element) have a default *max* attribute, so within an inline listener, the identifier *max* will reference the input's *max* property. Hence in any document:

```
<input onclick="console.log(max)">
```

shows `''` (i.e. empty string).

So you can either change the names of the functions to something more meaningful, or change the context from which they are called so that the identifiers aren't resolved on the element, and the OP code works. e.g.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="callBoth()">
```

and

```
function callBoth() {
  max();
  min();
}
```

Incidentally, an input type submit outside a form is just a button, so you should use:

```
<input type="button" ...>
```